# Search and visualize android devices from ios devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I learned to use the new ios7 API for peer to peer communication and works fine but only between ios devices. So this is not my goal!
I need to make an ios app that discovers the nearby devices (ios or android) and only visualize name of the devices and an unique key (mac address I know that is deprecated into ios7).
Repeat I don't want communication between devices I want only to see nearby devices....
I would like to approach before the problem on ios then I will pass to android sdk.

Any idea?....

Comment: If you scan for BLE peripheral (there are sample code from Apple), they shouldn't discriminate if there are iDevices, Android Devices, or whatever other devices. So I suggest you to look for the Apple Sample Code with CoreBlutooth.framework.

Comment: yes I don't think that is a racism question!!! :D
I will try and I tell you my results.
Thank you very much for the reply....

Answer (score 2):

Android and iOS do not cooperate on BLE connections. The issue is explained in detail in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18757882/768935.

Shortly, you won't be able to do this until the https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58725 issue is solved.

Alternatively, you can use e.g. the Bump API to implement the connection (and it's a lot funnier too) https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984325/768935

Comment: Unfortunately BUMP not will be yet supported (and will be closed) by the Company after the acquisition by Google. So I don't want to spend time to develop on a technology pratically ended... (http://bu.mp/company/api)
Thanks a lot for the reply.... I will wait better times!

Comment: I suspect Google is going to revive it in some form. Hopefully as accessible as it was. Unfortunately, I don't know of real alternatives. Bump is amazing! Otherwise, did I answer your question?

Comment: I didn't mention Bonjour as I couldn't find a reasonable implementation for Android back then. If you find one, please let us know.

Comment: I've initiated to dig into the Android SDK! If I find a solution I will write to you.

Comment: If anyone has solution for this!! Please let me know also..Thanks for this question and answer!!