# Bluetooth connect between ios and android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I know it had been asked many times about connect Ios and android via bluetooth.

I just want to know if android os update to 4.3 and use the bluetooth four-chip,it is any possible for their connection?

I only need receive some bytes from android device,then display on the Ios device.

Comment: the limit comes from apple. Duplicate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080644/is-it-possible-in-principle-for-an-android-device-to-interface-with-an-iphone?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

for now, the answer is no. And I am talking about the newest bluetooth low energy technology.
Since android 4.3, you can now turn your android device into a central, listening to other peripherals's advertisement. However as of today, android 4.4.2, google still haven't realised any public api which allows you to turn android into a peripheral(like a broadcaster). So you can't advertise or send data. Although I did see a page saying you can do it privately, I haven't tried it yet.
http://blog.cozybit.com/enabling-peripheral-mode-in-android-kitkat-4-4/

On the iOS side, in iOS7, apple added new apis and now you can turn your iPhone into either a peripheral or central(not at the same time). So it is ok for inter-iOS exchanges, while android can only listen and receive data from iOS. You can try searching iKardz on the App Store and see how it's done on 2 iOS devices.
http://www.ikardz.me

However, the story didn't end here. Due to some bugs in google bluetooth apis, you can't actually connect to any smart devices for now, for details please see this link.
[Communicating between iOS and Android with Bluetooth LE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410081/communicating-between-ios-and-android-with-bluetooth-le)
SO for the record, this limit DID NOT come from apple.