# How to build an android app that acts as a peripheral bluetooth, so I can discover it from iOS application?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, gatt

I have built an iOS app that uses corebluetooth, and an android app that starts avertisement via GATT server.

So Android devices only discover other androids and iOS devices.

And iOS devices discovers other iOS' only.

The question is how to advertise data from android so iOS devices can discover it, or is there any way for iOS device to scan regular bluetooth devices except for MFi program?

if you had any experience with connecting these two OS via bluetooth, please let me know the ways on how to do it.

Comment: You can refer to the 2nd answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410081/communicating-between-ios-and-android-with-bluetooth-le

Comment: as far as i understoon, it is not possible as for now. Unfortunate.